# SQL grouping issue - multiples of the same style code

Tags: sql, sql-server

At the moment i have ranked my SQL by product name and ordered by start date. What I want to do now is group by group,row,style ( i want to end up with 4 rows having 2 rows for style 27823) this is why i tried to include a rank so i could group by that also.. but it has obviously gave the rank of 1 for the style 27823 so i still get 3 rows.

```
SELECT 
   PS.SECTION_NAME [Planning Group],
   PR.ROW_NAME [Planning Row],
   P.PRODUCT_NAME [Style],  
   (SD.START_DATE) [Start dt],
   dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY P.PRODUCT_NAME) rank_ 

FROM 
   tables_

Order by
   PS.SECTION_NAME,
   PR.ROW_NAME,
   SD.START_DATE
```

What I have:

```
Group    Row       Style    Start dt        rank_
SEW      LS-1-A    27823    2015-12-12      1
SEW      LS-1-A    A8AR     2015-12-13      2
SEW      LS-1-A    NFJ3BH03 2016-01-06      3
SEW      LS-1-A    27823    2016-02-17      1
SEW      LS-1-A    27823    2016-03-03      1
SEW      LS-1-A    27823    2016-03-12      1
SEW      LS-1-A    27823    2016-03-20      1
SEW      LS-1-A    27823    2016-03-24      1
```

I would like to get the 'NEW_RANK_COLUMN' worked in so i can group by that.

```
Group    Row       Style    Start dt        rank_    NEW_RANK_COLUMN
SEW      LS-1-A    27823    2015-12-12      1        1
SEW      LS-1-A    A8AR     2015-12-13      2        2
SEW      LS-1-A    NFJ3BH03 2016-01-06      3        3
SEW      LS-1-A    27823    2016-02-17      1        4
SEW      LS-1-A    27823    2016-03-03      1        4
SEW      LS-1-A    27823    2016-03-12      1        4
SEW      LS-1-A    27823    2016-03-20      1        4
SEW      LS-1-A    27823    2016-03-24      1        4
```

The results I'm trying to get is:

```
 Group  Row     Style       
 SEW    LS-1-A  27823    
 SEW    LS-1-A  A8AR       
 SEW    LS-1-A  NFJ3BH03  
 SEW    LS-1-A  27823
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to take the date into account when defining the rank -- keeping consecutive values the same.  One method is to use `lag()` to see when the value changes and then take the cumulative sum of that value:

```
SELECT PS.SECTION_NAME [Planning Group], PR.ROW_NAME as [Planning Row],
       P.PRODUCT_NAME [Style], (SD.START_DATE) as [Start dt],
       SUM(isChange) OVER (PARTITION BY group ORDER BY start_dt) as rank_
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (CASE WHEN lag(row) over (partition by group order by start_dt) = row
                   THEN 0
                   ELSE 1
              END) as IsChange
      FROM tables_ t
     ) t
Order by PS.SECTION_NAME, PR.ROW_NAME, SD.START_DATE;
```

These functions work in SQL Server 2012+.  In earlier versions, you can do something similar using `outer apply`.

Comment: Given the sample data is only 1 group and 1 row it is not clear on partition by.  Great answer